# How to implement search for bookname, isbn, and author?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a Node - MongoDb backend for a book search application. I am storing book information such as ISBN, authors, Title, publisher, location etc. I implemented Title search as follows:

```
const bookTitle= new RegExp(escapeRegex(request.params.query), 'gi');
```

and then do a {title: bookTitle} search using .find method.

I want to understand at a high level how do I make it possible so that the user can type in author, isbn or the title, and be able to search through those properties in MongoDb.

I was thinking along the lines of checking if the query is a 10 digit number and then doing isbn search for that case? am I on the right track?

Comment: Another thing that I thought is to create another property in which I store isbn + '  ' + authors +  ' '  + title. This way I can perform one search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there are multiple solutions to this. Assuming you'd like to perform an `OR` query (i.e., return results where query term matches `author` OR `title` OR `ISBN`) you can do this with the proper indexes and [the $or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator.

I would likely start with a collection that broke out each of these field individual:

```js
{
  "_id" : 7, 
  "title" : "coffee and cream", 
  "author" : "John Doe", 
  "isbn" : 12312318
}

db.articles.createIndex( { author : 1 } )
db.articles.createIndex( { isbn : 1 } )
db.articles.createIndex( { title: "text" } )
```

You'll need to add the indexes on each of these field...take a look at the `text` index type and [`$text` queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) which would really help out for the `title` field (note, you can only use *one* `$text` index per collection).  Also read up on how [indexes work with $regex queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) which could be useful for querying the `author`.

When you get a query term, simply query for all fields.  An `$or` query would then return results which match any of these fields

Taking the [example in the $text documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#examples) and modifying it for this solution...assume the following records:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "subject" : "coffee", "author" : "xyz", "views" : 50, "isbn" : 12312312 }
{ "_id" : 2, "subject" : "Coffee Shopping", "author" : "efg", "views" : 5, "isbn" : 12312313 }
{ "_id" : 3, "subject" : "Baking a cake", "author" : "abc", "views" : 90, "isbn" : 12312314 }
{ "_id" : 4, "subject" : "baking", "author" : "xyz", "views" : 100, "isbn" : 12312315 }
{ "_id" : 5, "subject" : "Café Con Leche", "author" : "abc", "views" : 200, "isbn" : 12312316 }
{ "_id" : 6, "subject" : "Сырники", "author" : "jkl", "views" : 80, "isbn" : 12312317 }
{ "_id" : 7, "subject" : "coffee and cream", "author" : "efg", "views" : 10, "isbn" : 12312318 }
{ "_id" : 8, "subject" : "Cafe con Leche", "author" : "xyz", "views" : 10, "isbn" : 12312319 }
{ "_id" : 10, "subject" : "The Coffee Book: Anatomy of an Industry from Crop to the Last Drop", "author" : "Nina Luttinger", "isbn" : 1595580603 }
```

#### Searching for author:

```
> db.articles.find({ $or: [ 
     { $text: { $search: "lutt" } }, 
     { isbn: 'lutt' }, 
     { author: /lutt/i } 
  ] } )
{ "_id" : 10, "subject" : "The Coffee Book: Anatomy of an Industry from Crop to the Last Drop", "author" : "Nina Luttinger", "isbn" : 1595580603 }
```

#### Searching for title:

```
> db.articles.find({ $or: [ 
     { $text: { $search: "cafe" } }, 
     { isbn: 'cafe' }, 
     { author: /cafe/i } 
  ] } )
{ "_id" : 5, "subject" : "Café Con Leche", "author" : "abc", "views" : 200, "isbn" : 12312316 }
{ "_id" : 8, "subject" : "Cafe con Leche", "author" : "xyz", "views" : 10, "isbn" : 12312319 }
```

You could also do some basic logic on the server side to check whether the query term is an integer and either drop the `isbn` query operator from the search or query for *only* `isbn` if the query *is* an integer.  This would mean the queries above would simply not contain the `isbn` field in the list of `$or` queries.